# JAva cannot find symbol-exception handling

Tags: java, exception

I am new to exception handling, while running the given code the compiler displays an error message regarding the getmessage method and variable e in catch block.
where i am going wrong?
[image: Exception class]

[image: main file]

Comment: 1) Don't post your code as images.  One reason is that we can't compile code in images to see what the error messages.  2) DO post the compilation error messages. And not as images either.

Comment: will keep in mind from the next time,actually the platform was not allowing me to copy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception has a getMessage(), not getmessage().